# Как правильно писать "полутораспальная кровать"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, слитно-дефис

Как правильно написать: ***полутораспальная*** кровать?

Answer (score 3):

> Как правильно писать - **полутораспальная** кровать

Вы правильно написали. См. [проверку слова на gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EF%EE%EB%F3%F2%EE%F0%E0%F1%EF%E0%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9).

Answer (score 0):

[**Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/220837/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0...) :

**полутора...**
Начальная часть сложных слов, вносящая значение:
мерою в полторы единицы, указанной во второй части слова (полуторагодовой, полутораметровый, полуторарублёвый, полуторатонный и т.п.).

[**Энциклопедический словарь**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/130768/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0...):
Полуторавековой, полуторагодичный, полуторамесячный, полутораметровый, полуторапроцентовый, ***полутораспальный*.**

[**Орфографический словарь**](http://orfo.info/word/polutoraspalynjijy.php): ***полутораспальный.***